# valor de variable no cambia - PLY yacc

Tags: python, interfaz-gráfica, yacc

Estoy trabajando en crear una interfaz gráfica para un analizador de código de Typescript con PLY, y en mi código correspondiente al sintáctico tengo lo siguiente:

```
sintactico.py
error = ""
def p_error(p):
    global error
    error = ""
    if p:
        error = p
        print("sintactico.py IF -> Error en token ", p)
    else:
        error = "EOF"
        print("sintactico.py IF -> Error: se encontró EOF")
    print("sintactico.py -> ", error)

syntax = yacc.yacc()
```

Donde yo puedo comprobar que efectivamente la función detecta los errores en sintaxis. Ahora en mi archivo donde estoy creando la UI llamo a la variable error pero esta por algún motivo no cambia el valor del primer error que encuentre y lo mantiene en todas las iteraciones.

```
main.py
import sintactico
for code in codigo:
   # ANÁLISIS SINTÁCTICO
   parser = sintactico.syntax.parse(code)
   r_error = sintactico.error     #mantiene valor del primer error que encuentre
   print("main.py -> ", r_error)
   item_syn = QListWidgetItem(code)
   if r_error == "EOF":
      texto = code +"\nError en linea "+str(linea)+"\nPosible error: EOF inesperado"
      item_syn = QListWidgetItem(texto)
      item_syn.setForeground(QColor(255,0,0))
   elif r_error != "":
      token_p = sintactico.error
      texto = code +"\nError en linea "+str(token_p.lineno)+"\nPosible error: "+str(token_p.value)
      item_syn = QListWidgetItem(texto)
      item_syn.setForeground(QColor(255,0,0))
      self.list_syn.addItem(item_syn)
   print(parser)
   linea += 1
   r_error = ""
            
   self.inp_codigo.clear()
```

No detecto cuál sería el error si al iterar el arreglo código se supone que son diferentes análisis, por tanto el valor de r_error debería cambiar.

Answer (score 0):

Lo arreglé agregando sintactico.error = "" justo antes de la última línea, dentro del bucle for. Supongo que eso permite que sintactico.error se actualice como debe.